# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)

Tags: magento2, php, error, memory

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\magento4\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\Config\Placeholder.php on line 146

Hi when trying to start magento 2 for the first time I get this error i tried changing the memory size in php.ini (XAMPP), in htaccess and also in the root folder of magento. I also tried fixing it in cli but i still get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure both fields **secure** and **unsecure base_url** are filled with proper value.

May be you are directly adding the incorrect value to **core_config_data**. Magento cannot parse it, and it causes an infinite recursion. If you want to remove some value from **core_config_data**, you should delete the whole record, not only it's "value" raw.

Comment: Thank you. My problem was solved